# Spring Integration to pickup only based from the filename specified by a trigger file

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

Using spring integration, I want to pickup only the files based from the filename specified by a trigger file.

E.g.  batch01.tar will be picked up if .batch01-trigger is present then update the filename of the trigger depending on the processing outcome (.batch01-trigger.success or .batch01-trigger.failed)

I am polling S3 bucket at the moment but I couldn't apply the above use case.

Thanks!

I used AWS SDK and spring-integration-aws.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a solution like this:

1. Have an `S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` configured for the `*-trigger` pattern. So, it is going to poll S3 directory periodically for presence of the files like yours `.batch01-trigger`.
2. You send this file downstream to some service activator which would use an `S3Session.list()` and filter out only matching files. Or `public InputStream readRaw(String source) {` since you know at this point the file name (`batch01.tar`) you need to pull from an S3.
3. The trigger file you store in the message headers at this point.
4. After processing `.tar` file you make a `.success` or `.failed` decision and perform `S3Session.rename()`.